Is it normal to have discrepancies in Created Dates for fresh install?
I need to get corroborating opinions as to why the following occurred or may occur. I deleted Macintosh HD Volume Group which contains the two volumes Macintosh HD and Macintosh Data. I then reinstalled macOS on May 22, 2024. However, all files and directories are dated May 7th, 2024 12:01 AM. Perhaps that is when the software was created although it has the Date Added, Date Created, and Date Modified all as May 7th, 2024.
The reason I am concerned is because I was hacked into, and Mac experts brought up the possibility for boot malware. In fact, I have a different Mac in which I did the same exact reinstall on May 15th, 2024, and it itself has the same May 7th, 2024 12:01 AM date. Is this typical and to be expected install behavior?
To clarify, is it normal when doing a system restore on May 22nd 2024 for the files and directories installed to have created, modified, and added dates that differ from May 22nd 2024?

What is the discrepancy?

Between the actual install date of the OS and the created, modified, and added date that I inherited. I mentioned two dates that differ. Now maybe that’s normal. I don’t know.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Which version of macOS are you installing?

So you installed the same version of macOS on two different Macs, and the dates of the files/directories installed are identical on both? Where exactly do you see a discrepancy?

Having said that: I have a bunch of OS directories/files dated May 7th, 09:01, assume this is (considering time zones) the same date as well.

I clarified above. Thanks.

Please help me understand the issue. You installed the same version of macOS on Mac A on May 15th, on May B on May 22nd. In both cases, the installed OS has timestamps with May 7th. IMHO you have your answer right there, what is missing?

My guess, yes, was that since they are pulling from a common source that they would pull the same dates. I thought when you did an install, however, that the Added Dates would be updated to show the install dates. For me, the Added Date, Modified Date, and Created Dates are fixed at May 22nd 2024. Should I conclude that this is normal?

What you are seeing is expected.
All Macs running the same version of macOS have an identical read only Macintosh HD with identical files with identical dates. The displayed times will vary depending on time zone.
My iMac with macOS 14.5 shows 7 May 2024 at 17:01 (time zone +10hr) for files installed as part of macOS.
Other files (including any apps you have installed) will have different dates.  Note that Apple apps installed from the Apple App Store (e.g. Pages) are not part of the read only Macintosh HD and have their own dates.

I got my independent corroboration. This will satisfy me. Thank you. So the created date will be when Apple developers created the files, but why would the Added Dates be the same as the Created Dates? Perhaps only Apple knows. Yes, I am aware that the Apple Store is a different kind of beast.

@joncavaz Both files and folders are exactly the same on all Macs. All files were added to the folders on 7th May. And it is in that state that your Macintosh HD is created. It really is identical!
